# Create a event inside a procedure

Tags: mariadb

Using Mariadb 10.5.13 is it possible to create a event inside a procedure ?

The reason is because I would like to have a procedure I can manually trigger, and then run a one time event 3-4 hours later.

I don't know if I'm failing because of syntax error or because this is just not allowed

If possible how would you create a procedure that just sleep for 60s, then create a event to run again in 4 hours and sleep for 80s (just need to learn the syntax, the queries inside doesn't matter much)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an event procedure within stored procedure.

> The reason is because I would like to have a procedure I can manually trigger, and then run a one time event 3-4 hours later.

This is simple enough. Do you have any service table in your database(s) or in any service or system database? if not then create it, like

```sql
CREATE TABLE serviceDB.serviceTable (
    domainName VARCHAR(255),
    parameterName VARCHAR(255),
    parameterValue LONGBLOB,
    PRIMARY KEY (domainName, parameterName)
);
```

Now you create a row like

```sql
INSERT INTO serviceDB.serviceTable (domainName, parameterName, parameterValue)
VALUES ('myApplication', 'executeMyEventProcedure', NOW() + INTERVAL 4 HOURS);
```

The event procedure checks this parameter value and performs the action if the execution is set:

```sql
CREATE EVENT myEventProcedure
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT NULL       -- check does we need to perform the proc action 
                FROM serviceDB.serviceTable 
                WHERE domainName = 'myApplication'
                  AND parameterName = 'executeMyEventProcedure'
                  AND parameterValue <= NOW()) THEN
        UPDATE serviceDB.serviceTable      -- reset the flag for to avoid re-launch
        SET parameterValue = NULL
        WHERE domainName = 'myApplication'
          AND parameterName = 'executeMyEventProcedure'
          AND parameterValue <= NOW();
-- perform needed actions
    END IF;
END
```